# $B$-tight frame (Tao and Kadison Singer)

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I am just trying to understand [this](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/11/04/real-stable-polynomials-and-the-kadison-singer-problem/#ks2) text from Tao:

$\renewcommand{\C}{\mathbb C}$
Assume you have $w_1,\ldots,w_m \in \C^d$ and $B > 0$ with 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m |\langle w_i, u \rangle |^2 = B
$$ for all unit-vectors $u \in \C^d$. Can we conclude that 
$$
 \sum_{i=1}^m w_iw_i^* = \sum_{i=1}^m |w_i\rangle \langle w_i| = BI_{\C^d}
$$ where $(w_iw_i^*)(v) = \langle w_i, v \rangle w_i$ for all $v \in \C^d$. We also know tat $||w_i|| \leq A$ for some $A > 0$, but I don't think that this is relevant.

I just showed that 
$$
\langle \sum_i w_iw_i^* e_k, e_k \rangle = B,
$$ but I want also that 
$$
\langle \sum_i w_iw_i^* e_k, e_l\rangle = 0
$$ if $k \neq l$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $W=\sum_{i=1}^m w_iw_i^\ast\in M_d(\mathbb C)$. Then $W$ is positive semidefinite and hence it possesses a complete eigenbasis. Since $u^\ast Wu \equiv \sum_{i=1}^m|\langle w_i,u\rangle|^2 = B$ for every unit vector $u$, when $u$ is taken to be a unit eigenvector of $W$, we see that every eigenvalue of $W$ is equal to $B$. Therefore $W$ is $B$ times the identity matrix.

Comment: Thanks. So I think that it is useful to do all computations in this eigenbasis of $\mathbb C^d$.